# Function App Upgrade .netCore3.1 to .net6.0 - EventHub Trigger Error

Tags: azure-functions, .net-6.0, eventtrigger

I am working on function app upgrade from .net3.1 to .net6.0.
My event Hub Trigger function was working fine in .net3.1. After upgradation to .net6.0 and upgrading to all the eventhub packages to latest version  - I am getting below issue.

**Error MEssage when Entity path added in the EventHub Connection string:**
System.ArgumentException: 'The path to an Event Hub may be specified as part of the connection string or as a separate value, but not both.  Please verify that your connection string does not have the `EntityPath` token if you are passing an explicit Event Hub name. (Parameter 'connectionString')'

After removing entity path from connection string. Getting below issue.

Error Message:
The listener for function 'CCCCXXX' was unable to start. System.Private.CoreLib: One or more errors occurred. (The messaging entity 'xxxxxxyyyyyy-02.servicebus.windows.net/eventhubname' could not be found.

My Packages

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs" Version="4.3.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor" Version="4.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
```

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.10">
```

Comment: Can you post the Function declaration?

Comment: \[FunctionName("TestFunction")]
        public async Task Testfunction([EventHubTrigger("EventHubName", Connection = "MyConnectionString", ConsumerGroup = "test_group")] EventData[] events,
       ILogger log)
        {
            foreach (EventData eventData in events)
            {
            }
        }     @MattDouhan

Comment: ok and you have the settings for EventHubName and MyConnectionString set? and you are not changing from dotnet to dotnet-isolated right?

Comment: We are using dotnet not dotnet -isoleated .yes i have settings mapped .  Below is the settings . {
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "MyConnectionString": "Endpoint=sb://xxxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=tttttttt=;EntityPath=xxxxx-yyyyy",
    "EventHubName": "xxxyy-asaoutput",
    "ConsumerGroup": "xxx",
    "DbName": "yyy",
   
  } @matt douhan

Comment: It seems to be you are passing the event hub connection string variable in place of the storage conn string variable in the code. Please check!

Answer (score 0):

> The path to an Event Hub may be specified as part of the connection string or as a separate value, but not both. Please verify that your connection string does not have the `EntityPath` token if you are passing an explicit Event Hub name.

This issue is registered in the [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/3034) of Azure Functions Core Tools for both Event Hub Trigger and IoT Hub Triggers when migrating from .NET 3.1 to .NET 6.

Many authors mentioned the causes of this error along with the fix is:

1. If the ConnectionString - EntityPath value is not matched properly with the eventHubName in the EventHub Trigger.
2. Also, upgrade the package if not done - i.e., from `Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs` package to `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs`.
3. Try removing the `EntityPath` token from the Event Hub Connection string.
4. Refer to the [thomgre](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/3034#issuecomment-1157685441) GitHub comment on specifying the EventHub Connection string on Function declaration will fix this type of errors.

Comment: Hi @Hari krishna - thanks for your response. I tried all the above steps. Now i am getting different error - the messaging entity https://sb.entity.######/evenhubname could not be bound

Comment: Reopen the issue by mentioning the steps you have followed from that github reference in this GitHub Azure Functions Issues [Page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues)